# Looking for a Javascript Ui framework for desktop and mobile application development

Tags: javascript-framework

I am currently trying to complete a project which needs to have a mobile application as well as a desktop application. And I am looking for a framework to allow me to do it.

Are there any platforms out there that satisfy the Desktop + Mobile App production from the same stock of code?

Your help will be greatly appreciated in solving my dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing to much about the exact requirements of your application i would say your best bet is to go with **Sencha Ext JS JavaScript Framework for Rich Desktop Apps!**

Sencha Ext JS is the industry's most powerful desktop application development platform with unparalleled cross-browser compatibility, advanced MVC architecture, plugin-free charting, and modern UI widgets.

**Check them out: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs**

Answer (score -1):

You mention `javascript` and `UI` in the same breath. Javascript does not really do UI. you use CSS to do UI.

However, have you looked at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)?

If you are looking for a responsive UI design frameworks, you should have a look at

1. [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
2. [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

They both allow you to make UI that adjusts itself for the device it is being rendered on

There are client side javascript based application frameworks such as [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/), [Angular JS](http://angularjs.org/) and many more. These frameworks are a great help in building applications that work well on mobile devices as well as desktop browsers.

Comment: Yes. I have taken a look of Jquery UI. but looking For responsive UI framework. like YUI/ExtJS give ready UI for desktop..

Comment: I need Framework which should work both side (Desktop + Mobile App production from the same stock of code)..